# Why clone object in yii2 pagination

Tags: php, pagination, clone, yii2

Here in [pagination doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html) they're using  $countQuery = clone $query;  Why? It works without clone and produce the same sql queries in result as clone would. Help me find a difference please.

Answer (score 3):

Advantage of [**clone**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) over creation a new object, is that, all properties will be copied into the new object instead of resetting them. This is quite useful when you use query builder. In the official document example, we have:

```
$query = Article::find()->where(['status' => 1]);
$countQuery = clone $query;
```

If you get a dump from `$query` and `$countQuery` you can see, `$countQuery` is a new object just like `$query` and it has also `status=>1`. In these cases, we use clone to have two near-identical queries with slight differences. So you can have multiple behavior from a `Query Object` . This will become more useful when you have complex query builder objects that you may need to have a little difference from your existing query. For instance, You need to have a `union`. You don't want to rewrite your `Query` object, do you? So the best way would be getting a clone from existing query, then change its behavior.

Comment: Good answer, but I think the questioner meant to ask why not use the same object again instead of cloning it. The answer to that is because calling count (potentially) changes the inner state of the active query which may give unexpected results when run again.

Comment: As user above has mentioned - I've asked about why not use the same object? Using count method doesn't change any state of $query object. It will run the same queries, I've checked. So, was it just for futher usage flexibility, or it has some meaning already in the example given?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant why you should clone the object instead of reusing it, the answer is that calling the count function on the object might change it's internal state. If you then re-use the same object it might give unexpected results.